# How do I select the EndDate and StartDate values with an XML like this using XPath?

Tags: c#, xpath, selector

I want to be able to pinpoint the `EndDate`/`StartDate` value, but all the samples I see online looks like this:

```
<Parameter name="StartDate">01-01-2017 00:00:00</Parameter>
```

So, given this:

```
<Parameters>
    <Parameter>
        <Name>EndDate</Name>
        <Value>01-01-2017 00:00:00</Value>
    </Parameter>
    <Parameter>
        <Name>StartDate</Name>
        <Value>01-01-2013 00:00:00</Value>
    </Parameter>
</Parameters>
```

How do I get `StartDate`?

Answer (score 0):

The [`following-sibling` axis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) is a key to solving the problem:

```
//Parameter/Name[. = 'StartDate']/following-sibling::Value
```

Or, you can first locate the desired `Parameter` node and then get the `Value`:

```
//Parameter[Name = 'StartDate']/Value
```